# Lua - Can I pick the specific result(s) I want from a function that returns multiple results

Tags: lua

Is there a way to choose the result(s) I want from a function that returns multiple results . E.g.

```
local function FormatSeconds(secondsArg)

    local weeks = math.floor(secondsArg / 604800)
    local remainder = secondsArg % 604800
    local days = math.floor(remainder / 86400)
    local remainder = remainder % 86400
    local hours = math.floor(remainder / 3600)
    local remainder = remainder % 3600
    local minutes = math.floor(remainder / 60)
    local seconds = remainder % 60
    
    return weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds
    
end

FormatSeconds(123456)
```

What would I use to only grab just one e.g  `hours`, or two  `minutes` &  `seconds`

Comment: `hours = ({FormatSeconds(123456)})[3]` and `minutes, seconds = select(4, FormatSeconds(123456))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way without altering the return type of the function:

```lua
local weeks, _, _, _, _ = FormatSeconds(123456) -- Pick only weeks
print(weeks)
```

To pick more than one result:

```lua
local _, _, _, minutes, seconds = FormatSeconds(123456)
io.write(minutes, " minutes ", seconds, " seconds")
```

Comment: Note that `local` should be used to avoid creating an `_` global (or other globals for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply return an array (or I think table in lua) and then index which result you want

```
local function FormatSeconds(secondsArg)

    local weeks = math.floor(secondsArg / 604800)
    local remainder = secondsArg % 604800
    local days = math.floor(remainder / 86400)
    local remainder = remainder % 86400
    local hours = math.floor(remainder / 3600)
    local remainder = remainder % 3600
    local minutes = math.floor(remainder / 60)
    local seconds = remainder % 60

    return {weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds}

end
-- weeks = 1, days = 2, hours = 3, minutes = 4, seconds = 5

print(FormatSeconds(123456)[3])
```

You could also use key value pairs and index that way

```
return {["weeks"] = weeks, ["days"] = days, ["hours"] = hours, ["minutes"] = minutes, ["seconds"] = seconds}
```

Then print this way

```
print(FormatSeconds(123456)["hours"])
```

Or one more simpler solution

```
local function FormatSeconds(secondsArg)

    arr = {}

    arr["weeks"] = math.floor(secondsArg / 604800)
    local remainder = secondsArg % 604800
    arr["days"] = math.floor(remainder / 86400)
    local remainder = remainder % 86400
    arr["hours"] = math.floor(remainder / 3600)
    local remainder = remainder % 3600
    arr["minutes"] = math.floor(remainder / 60)
    arr["seconds"] = remainder % 60
    
    return arr
    
end

print(FormatSeconds(123456)["hours"])
```